# Try Except block for multiple validation errors

Tags: python, json, try-catch, except

```
try: 
    if isDateValid(date) == false:
        raise ValidationError('invalid date')
    if usernameValid(user) == false:
        raise ValidationError('invalid username')
except ValidationError:
    data = json.dumps({'status': 'Enter a valid date'})
    data = json.dumps({'status': 'Enter a valid username'})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(data, content_type='application/json')`
```

How can I make data = the correct message depending on where the error is thrown or the message passed?

Comment: Why are you using try/except at all? You could just set the `data` var directly in those if statements. And that would solve your message customization q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the exception instance you are raising:

```
try: 
    if isDateValid(date) == false:
        raise ValidationError('invalid date')
    if usernameValid(user) == false:
        raise ValidationError('invalid username')
except ValidationError as e:
    data = json.dumps({'status': str(e)})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Well, the above will produce `'status': 'invalid date'`. If you want to give the message `'enter a valid date'` you have to see which message got passed:

```
except ValidationError as e:
    msg = 'Enter a valid '
    if str(e).endswith('date'):
        msg += 'date'
    else:
        msg += 'username'
    data = json.dumps({'status': msg})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Or even simpler:

```
except ValidationError as e:
    msg = 'Enter a valid ' + str(e)[len('invalid '):]
    data = json.dumps({'status': msg})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(data, content_type='application/json')
```

---

Personally you should ask yourself *whether* you could just use two different subclasses of `ValidationError` for the two different conditions.
You could have `InvalidUsernameError` and `InvalidDateError` and catch them separately. **This would surely produce a much more robust solution** (you aren't relying on the exact text passed to the raised exception), even though going too deep with class hierarchies isn't generally a good thing.